# How to get Bindpose from COLLADA Schema Version 1.4.1?

Tags: animation, 3d, collada

parent_bone's bindpose is missing if collada file didn't include parent_bone in <library_controllers> when I export collada file from Blender 3+ if I didn't include parent_bone then bindpose will not include too.

I try to get Bindpose with my Parser c++ from Collada file.

Blender can render with correct result even Bindpose is missing in Collada file.

So I Think I need to get Bindpose by calculation or some way to not use Bindpose but use other data in <library_visual_scenes> or other.

I need Bindpose for 3D Skinning calculation.